# unable to replace everything with empty between two characters

Tags: regex, bash, jq, gsub

I am trying to extract the "stack name" portion of the AWS ARN string. The string looks like this:

```
arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:stack/infrastructure-dev/aaaaaaaa-f005-11e9-9e45-02bf7f1fc1f4
```

The issue isn't so much extracting than it is replacing an original key with a modified original value, using jq.

my statement is as follows:

```
aws cloudformation list-exports --no-paginate | jq -r '.Exports |= map(if .ExportingStackId != "" then .ExportingStackId |= sub("(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)"; "") else . end)'
```

The **`sub("(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)"; "")`** command will match, but it will replace the portion of the string with empty.

```
{
  "Exports": [
    {
      "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:stack//aaaaaaaa-f005-11e9-bbbb-aaaaaaaa",
      "Name": "BootstrapRoleArn",
      "Value": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/deployment-role"
    },
    {
      "ExportingStackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:stack//aaaaaaaa-f005-11e9-bbbb-aaaaaaaa",
      "Name": "PrivateSubnetAId",
      "Value": "subnet-44444444444"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

I require the inverse of that, whereby everything else surrounding that porton of the string is set to empty

```
{
  "Exports": [
    {
      "ExportingStackId": "infrastructure-dev",
      "Name": "BootstrapRoleArn",
      "Value": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/deployment-role"
    },
    {
      "ExportingStackId": "infrastructure-prod",
      "Name": "PrivateSubnetAId",
      "Value": "subnet-44444444444"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

As an "extra challenge", I would really like to be able to remove the appended portion of the "-dev" or "-prod" too, such that the output would be:

```
{
  "Exports": [
    {
      "ExportingStackId": "infrastructure",
      "Name": "BootstrapRoleArn",
      "Value": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/deployment-role"
    },
    {
      "ExportingStackId": "infrastructure",
      "Name": "PrivateSubnetAId",
      "Value": "subnet-44444444444"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `sub`, consider using `capture`, e.g.:

```
(capture(".*(?<x>(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)).*"; "") | .x)
```

The requirements regarding removing the -dev or -prod suffix are not so clear, but you might want to consider simply using `sub("-(dev|prod)$"; "")`, so that you'd end up with:

```
.Exports
  |= map(if .ExportingStackId != ""
     then .ExportingStackId 
            |= (capture(".*(?<x>(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)).*"; "")
                | .x 
                | gsub("-(dev|prod)$"; ""))
     else . end)
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Worked like a charm. My regex skills are subpar - what does <x> do in this context, given you're piping it through to | .x ?